# "Revoke USB debugging authorization" is not listed under Developer Options

Tags: android, adb

"Revoke USB debugging authorization" is not listed under Developer Options. I'm trying to remove the RSA fingerprints of my PC.

But I can see it while searching for it at the top of Developer Options. Prompt to remove the RSA fingerprints is not displayed if I select under search list.

I'm using Google Plus lollipop Custom ROM on a HTC device. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: I can see a "revoke all rights" button on my phone, can you not on your device?

Comment: @Richard Tingle - No, I can't see the option on my device.

Comment: Have you ever figured it out? Just noticed same thing with AICP ROM on Motorola G 2015.

Comment: Did you find what caused the issue?

Comment: No, I haven't figured out the answer for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I traced the lack of “Revoke USB debugging authorization” to a custom kernel I had applied (called BeastMode). Applying a different kernel resulted in “Revoke USB debugging authorization” being present and ADB operations getting authorized properly.

Answer (score 2):

As @Gili mentioned, a device with a custom kernel will not show the "Revoke USB..." option.

As @Alex P. mentioned, the keys can be manually cleared by deleting the folder.

However, different kernels will store those files in different locations. Possible locations are:

- /data/.android/adbkey.pub
- /data/adb/adb_keys
- /data/misc/adb/adb_keys

Answer (score 1):

On the device, user-installed keys are stored in `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`.

Just delete the file to remove all keys.

Comment: But, on my device, there are no files under that folder.

Comment: Here's a method I found to manually copy your machine's `adbkey.pub` to `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys`: [stackoverflow.com/a/58585698](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58585698/1454514)