# Android ADB devices unauthorized

Tags: android, adb, unauthorized, oneplusone

#### Configuration:

- Windows 8.1
- ADB version: 1.0.32
- Smartphone: Oneplus One

#### Problem

I installed the Samsung drivers as it is said to do. When I run the ADB devices command, it said **unauthorized**.

#### Already tried:

1. I've done everything that'd been said on this post: *https://stackoverflow.com/a/25546300/1848376*

   But the problem is that I don't get a prompt on the phone to tell me I must accept the connection.
2. When I run the command `adb shell`, here is the answer:

   ```
   error: device unauthorized.
   This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
   Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
   ```

I did "adb kill-server", but it didn't change anything. Why?

Comment: After trying all of the above, I started downloading lower AVD's to see if any others would work. API 28 and 27 still freeze up during boot, but API 26 started right up. Android Studio 3.1.3 I will try to uninstall and reinstall at a later date, but glad this is finally working again. Fresh install of Android Studio 3.1 after a fresh Windows 10 install after dealing with critical process error for almost a week without rectification.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Thankgod xda developers exist : http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-lg-g3/help/unable-to-access-adb-t2830087

Just had to delete adbkey file in C:Users/$Name/.android adbkey.pub was missing.

Restart after this and both files are there.

If this does not work : 
- Try Revoke USB DEBUGGING Authorization.
- Enable USB debugging again.

Comment: where is this key on a Mac ?

Comment: @mosaad /Users/$username$/.android

Comment: > Restart after this and both files are there  
As in reboot?  I'm on Windows and am stuck with an "unauthorized" device that just won't go away!  (But I haven't rebooted, cuz 2 millions windows open)

Comment: @tbone I know it's a late answer but you only need to restart the adb server.

Comment: deleted everything in that file and not only did it fix ADB over Network, but also USB

Comment: renamed to `.android.old` to be on the safe side, but as soon as I restarted adb server and revoked authorizations, my phone prompted me right away! @julestruong thanks!

Comment: @julestruong Thanks a lot its worked for me i am struggling with all my office device now i got the solution how to connect all those.

Answer (score 296):

1. Try Revoke USB DEBUGGING Authorization.
2. Enable USB debugging again.

It worked.

Comment: When you re-enable USB debugging, it might be important to check the box that says always allow USB debugging from this device.  I believe this option will only show up if you have your Android device plugged to USB when you are re-enabling USB debugging.

Comment: I only had to disable and then enable USB debugging on my device, after moving to a new computer (Macbook).

Comment: Unplug then replug should be your first move anyway.

Comment: I never thought I get myself trapped in the "did you try to turn it off an on again?" :)

Comment: there is no option to Revoke USB DEBUGGING Authorization

Comment: Yea I disabled and re-enabled USB debugging, then unplugged/plugged it back into the workstation and it worked fine.

Comment: Worked even in Windows 11

Answer (score 41):

In sequence:

```
    adb kill-server
```

- in your DEVICE SETUP, go to developer-options end disable **usb-debugging**
- press REVOKE USB debugging authorizations, click OK
- enable **usb-debugging**

  ```
  adb start-server
  ```

Comment: I ran the command as root in Ubuntu and this solved my problem. Couldn't make it work without su (Ubuntu 18).

Answer (score 25):

I removed the following files from the *~/.android* folder:

- adbkey
- adbkey.pub

I disabled and enabled ADB within device and now it works...

Comment: I only saw `adbkey` file so I deleted it and it worked like charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

in Developer options,

1. Enable USB debugging.

[image]

2. Give a authorization.

[image]

(if there is no a Developer option menu, you have to click 3 times build number of Phone State menu to be developer. you can sse a developer option menu.)

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Delete existing **adbkeys**

*OR*

Rename **adbkeys**

Best practise is to *rename* the keys because it provides backup.

`cd ~/.Android`

`mv adbkey adbkey2`

`mv adbkey.pub adbkey.pub2`

*Next stop & start the server*

`cd ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`

Locate the device 
`/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb devices`

`/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb kill-server`

`/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb start-server`

Then, stop the emulator Open AVD manager, click on the down arrow, then click on **wipe data**

Restart the emulator. Then everything works fine :)

Comment: Didn't help. still get `platform-tools adb devices -> List of devices attached -> 192.168.0.185:5555 unauthorized`

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me

```
1- Go to ~/.android/ and remove “adbkey”
2- Disconnect USB connection
3- adb kill-server
4- Revoke USB debugging authorizations (in developer option)
5- Reconnect the device to the Ma
6- adb devices
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

Try this uncheck the "verify apps via USB" in developer options and then turn on and off the "USB Debugging". It works with me.

Comment: This method worked for me:
My "USB Debugging" was ON at first, then I uncheck "verify apps via USB" but this doesn't help. After I turn on then on "USB Debugging", it worked!

Comment: My device doesn't boot up.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that you have accepted the pressed the "ok" button when it is asking it is showing the fingerprint of the device after connecting through usb to your PC.

Comment: I wonder if people upvoting other answers actually checked the device screen…

Comment: LOL I felt pretty dumb when I looked down at my phone

Answer (score 4):

In Android studio, `Run menu > Run` shows `OFFLINE ...` for the connected device.

Below is the procedure followed to solve it:

1. (Read the below note first) Delete the `~/.android/adbkey` (or, rename to `~/.android/adbkey2`, this is even better incase you want it back for some reason)
   **Note**: I happened to do this step, but it didn't solve the problem, after doing all the below steps it worked, so unsure if this step is required.
2. Run `locate platform-tools/adb`
   **Note**: use the path that comes from here in below commands
3. Kill adb server:
   `sudo ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server`
4. You will get a `Allow accept..` message popup on your device. Accept it. This is important, which solves the problem.
5. Start adb server:
   `sudo ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server`
6. In Android studio, do `Run menu > Run` again
   It will show something like `Samsung ...` (your phone manufacture name).
   Also installs the apk on device correctly this time without error.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

None of the methods listed on this page worked for me; specifically:

- I had an issue where the Settings app would crash when selecting **Revoke USB debugging authorizations**
- I was running LineageOS 14 x86_64
- I was using ADB over network
- The `/data/misc/adb` contained no `adb_keys` file
- Removing my local `~/.android/adbkey` did not help either
- I had root access from the local terminal
- I was not getting any confirmation dialog

```
adb: error: failed to get feature set: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
- waiting for device -
```

In the end, I found a very useful post [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20191028041232/https://heapspray.io/usb-revocation-workaround.html) that suggested to manually put the contents of `~/.android/adbkey.pub` inside the `/data/misc/adb/adb_keys` file.

They suggested one of these two methods:

1. From another **working** device, copy the `adb_keys` file into your computer:

   ```bash
   # On the other Android device
   cp /data/misc/adb/adb_keys /sdcard
   ```

   ```bash
   # From your computer
   adb pull /sdcard/adb_keys .
   ```

   Then put the working `adb_keys` file into the problematic Android device's sdcard (using Web or MTP) named as `adb_keys`, then copy the file into the correct path:

   ```bash
   # On the problematic device
   cp /sdcard/adb_keys /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
   ```
2. The other method is to simply copy your machine's `adbkey.pub` from the `~/.android/` directory, and put it into the problematic Android device's sdcard (using Web or MTP) named as `adb_keys`, then copy the file into the correct path:

   ```bash
   # On the problematic device
   cp /sdcard/adbkey.pub /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
   ```

   (Note: there's a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42052776/1454514) on SO that goes into further details for this method.)

Since I was running a web server on my computer, and I had `curl` installed on Android, I `su`'ed from the terminal and ran the following on my Android device:

```bash
cd /data/misc/adb
curl 192.168.1.35:8080/adbkey.pub > adb_keys
```

Killed the `adb` daemon (using `adb kill-server`) and *BAM*! The `adb` shell worked fine, like it should have been from the beginning.

Hopefully, the method described here works for you as it did for me.

Answer (score 3):

1. First Remove the `adbkey` and `adbkey.pub` from the `.android` directory in your Home directory.
2. Make `.android` directory in your home with 710 permissions: `$ chmod 710 .android/` and ownership as: `chown -R <user>:<user> .android/`. Ex:

   ```
   $ chmod 710 .android/
   $ chown -R ashan:ashan .android/
   ```
3. Go to developer options in your mobile and tap option `Revoke USB debugging authorizations`
4. Turn off all `USB Debugging` and `Developer Options` in the device and disconnect the device from your machine.
5. Connect the device again and at first turn on the `Developer Options`. Then Turn on the `USB debugging`.
6. At this point in your mobile, you will get a prompt for asking permission from you. Note: you must check the checkbox `always accept from this ….` option and click ok.
7. Now in you machine, start the adb server: `adb start-server`.
8. Hopefully when you issue the command: `adb devices` now, you will see your device ready authorized.

Answer (score 1):

I was hit by this problem, too. I'm using my custom build of AOSP on Nexus 5X. I've added a single line in build/core/main.mk:

```
diff --git a/core/main.mk b/core/main.mk
index a6f829ab6..555657539 100644
--- a/core/main.mk
+++ b/core/main.mk
@@ -362,6 +362,8 @@ else # !enable_target_debugging
   ADDITIONAL_DEFAULT_PROPERTIES += ro.debuggable=0
 endif # !enable_target_debugging

+ADDITIONAL_DEFAULT_PROPERTIES += ro.adb.secure=1
+
 ## eng ##

 ifeq ($(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT),eng)
```

Now `adb shell` works fine

Those materials are useful (Chinese articles): http://www.voidcn.com/blog/kc58236582/article/p-6335996.html, http://blog.csdn.net/fanmengke_im/article/details/28389439

Answer (score 1):

> Try deleting the *adbkey* file from **C/.android** folder

and then run the commands as 
mentioned above i.e.

> adb kill-server, adb start-server and adb devices

.

Comment: Looks like, this is exactly what is detailed described below in post https://stackoverflow.com/a/55470951/984471

Answer (score 1):

Your app is being detected as some harmful program.
Turn off "Verify apps over USB" option. It's in the same view as "USB debugging".

Answer (score 1):

```
Disconnect USB between PC and device
Stop adb server by entering "adb kill-server" in command window
On device use "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" in "Developer Options"
On PC delete "adbkey" file in user directory, for example "C:\Users\Amit\.android"
Reconnect the device to the PC
Open a command window and enter "adb devices". Watch the device's screen for any Authorization message and allow the connection.
```

Comment: Adb devices shows the device (again) but says UNAUTHORISED and the pop up doesn't appear on the phone screen. I forced it to appear when opened android studio.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to authorize debug mode.
1. make sure your Device is connected to your PC. 
2. Allow authorized for debug mode via Android-Studio by going to 
 
Run -> Attach debugger to Android process 
than you will see the pop up window for allow debug mode in your Device,
 press OK. done.
i hope it help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after reinstalled my android studio. Here's what I did to make my adb work again:

```
-path to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
-Shift+r.click and start command from here instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone encountering this later this may also help.  I encountered this exact issue trying to use adb from a user command prompt and the answers above did not help, but the problem went away with an "adb kill-server" when running in an administrator command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

rm ~/.android/adbkey.pub

sudo ./adb kill-server

sudo ./adb start-server

sudo ./adb -s emulator-5554 install ~/apk_to_install.apk

I'm not sure if is a good idea run adb with sudo privileges,but it was the only way I get it works. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I got this as root when as a non-root user I was getting permissions errors trying to connect to custom recovery (Philz). so I killed adb server, copied the .android subdirectory of my user account into /root, chowned -R to root.root, and restarted adb server. I'm in!

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you have enabled On-device Developer Options in your smartphone? If not you can take a look at the steps provided by Android, http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#developer-device-options

Comment: Yes i did, and i also switch it off and on.

Comment: according to this link (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175077), it seems "platform tools 23 rc1" has this problem. You can find platform tool versions with "$ adb version" cmd . The link says that switching back to  build-tools version 22 fixes the issue.

Comment: I download plateform tools 22, and replaced it in sdk directory, didnt work (adb version seems to be the same though)

Answer (score -1):

For FIRE STICK 4K it actually says in the dialog:

**Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device**

Indeed on the TV in the other room there was a confirmation dialog. Doh'!

Comment: Maybe this could be a side comment to the question, but it's not an answer since the question is concerned with a different type of device.

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem and it wasnt solved by the deleting of any keys (at least deleting them didnt fix it, maybe had an effect after i did fix it though)

I actually had a discrepancy between my sdk-tools version and my Android Studio version. After updating my tools it still didnt work, but after updating AS (to 1.4) everything worked fine again.

Always update both sdk-tools and AS version together ;)