# Android Device won't connect to ADB

Tags: android, android-studio, osx-yosemite, nexus-7, nexus-5

Compiling Android Studio 1.3 on Yosemite machine to a 2013 N7 5.1.1 with USB Debugging enabled and connection set to MTP

1. device is detected
2. build is successful
3. Session 'app': running shows in event log

Nothing comes up on screen. Nothing installed to HD

(same process with same Android Studio machine compiles to N5 5.1.1)

EDIT- clearnig out ADB and installing drivers on Windows led to Mac detecting device correctly as N7 and this new set of errors on Mac:

PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device 06d8bddc: device unauthorized.
This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

EDIT- Yosemite identifying N7 as N7 and showing "ADB connection Error: EOF" in Device Manager
Windows 10 no longer recognizing device and refusing to install any Google Drivers for "Unknown USB device"

EDIT- Attemptd to clear out ADB RSA Keys. Keys were regenerated on Android Studio restart. Device status is still "offline"
[Android adb devices unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638582/android-adb-devices-unauthorized)

SOLUTION- Factory reset device and accept Google permission to periodically scan developer device

Comment: did you try adb kill-server then adb start-server ?

Comment: Whats the exact command I would run in the Android Studio terminal? I tried different ones for a couple minutes but I have never used the studio terminal

Comment: check the path to your adb if you dont have it in your path. then "adb kill-server" then "adb start-server"

Comment: Android ADB Interface is installed, tried MTP/PTP, tried cleaning project, tried resetting ADB through Device Monitor. Still showing [offline] in device showing up in 'choose device' panel. Device monitor throws "Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: There's a similar question about N7 with many answers. It might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993855/android-adb-device-offline-cant-issue-commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to do a factory reset on my device :(

After I enabled USB Debuginng and paired the device with my computer this new dialogue came up. This time I allowed Google to snoop on my developer device and everything worked! (I remember declining this setting months ago. I wish I had known this was A: no longer optional, B: possible to trigger somewhere in settings, C: came up as an issue in Android Studio when it was misbehaving)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging and plugging the USB back in to the computer, and if that does not work then try to switch PTP to MTP or MTP to PTP and back again.

You can also try going to your control panel and see if your computer detects it! Also check if you have installed the appropiate drivers to run the program!

Check here also: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html

Comment: USB unplug/replug - tried this. PTP/MTP swap - tried this. PC recognizes device - got this to work. 

I looked in the ADB log as suggested from your link and now see this new error: 

PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device 06d8bddc: device unauthorized.
This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

Comment: That's wierd... did you try replugging the USB after doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post http://zacktutorials.blogspot.ca/2012/08/nexus7-android-development.html which has the steps in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem several times. In this case I just open Run/Edit Configurations , edit something and run app again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an ASUS Memopad after it was upgraded to Android 5.0. I did not initially see the option to "Allow Google to periodically check for security problems", so I reset it to default, then the option was offered and it connected to AS without any problems.

I have subsequently found this option under:
 Google Settings/Verify Apps/Scan Device for security threats

So I would say that is the fix but it is not limited to the NEXUS 7.