# AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized on Android Studio only

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm switching over to Android Studio (2.1.1) from Eclipse.  I have an identical app on both platforms.   I have a stock Samsung phone running 4.2.2 fully enabled for USB debugging, attached via USB.

I build my app on Android Studio without errors or warnings, but when I do Debug "app" from the Run menu I get...

> com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
>   This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set Try 'adb kill-server' if
>   that seems wrong. Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your
>   device. Error while Installing APK

If I try to run or debug it from Eclipse I have **no problems**.

Eclipse is not running when I attempt to run it from Android Studio.

Similar messages have been reported several times (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638582/android-adb-devices-unauthorized)) but not in a context where it was working in Eclipse but not Android Studio so I don't think this is a duplicate.

What does...

> This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set Try 'adb kill-server'

...mean?