# ADB Android Device Unauthorized (No Revoke USB Debugging Authorizations) Nougat

Tags: android, adb

I suddenly have trouble using ADB to connect to one of my phone running Nougat. Like [How to Fix ADB Unauthorized Error](http://www.neuraldump.com/2017/05/how-to-fix-adb-unauthorized-error/)'s author, I do not have Revoke USB Debugging Authorizations option anywhere. Unlike the author, I still see an authorized device in my adb even after I boot into the recovery.

I also followed [Missing USB revocation on Android with Nethunter](https://heapspray.io/usb-revocation-workaround.html) with zero luck.

I tried to connect the same mobile device (Samsung S6) to another mac (never connected before) and encountered the identical issue...

Comment: you question helped me a lot .. first link that u had provided worked for me

Comment: This may help future visitors: [stackoverflow.com/a/58585698](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58585698/1454514)

Answer (score 0):

1. Android Device: Connect device via USB with 'file transfer' connection
2. PC: execute 'adb kill-server' followed by 'adb start-server'

You should be prompted for debug authorization in the android device following this process. If not please revoke all debug authorizations in android settings and repeat.