# Why do I see an Android emulator app run error?

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I am setup Android emulator and it's working. But, if I run command

```
cordova -d emaulator android
```

I see error

```
Failed to execute shell command "getprop,dev.bootcomplete"" on device: Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

The emulator started, but there is no application in it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43984410/3426262

I googled about this `error: device unauthorized.`

Make sure that you also tried to enable the developer options:

[image]